# PyQt make a widget inherit a different class's stylesheet?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I subclassed a QTableView and am using it as a table header (for another QTableView) because I needed a multi-level header and doing this was easier than subclassing a QHeaderView... however I would still like it to be automatically styled as if it were a QHeaderView, is this possible?

As a minimal example, I would like the table cells highlighted in red below to look like the header cells highlighted in green.

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

table_1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
table_1.setRowCount(1)
table_1.setColumnCount(5)
for tr in range(1):
    for tc in range(5):
        table_1.setItem(tr, tc, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(f"Item-{tr}-{tc}"))


table_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
table_2.setRowCount(1)
table_2.setColumnCount(5)
for tr in range(1):
    for tc in range(5):
        table_2.setItem(tr, tc, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(f"{tc+1}"))

table_2.horizontalHeader().hide()

table_1.show()
table_2.show()
app.setStyle("fusion")
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean and possibly provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante Okay I've added a minimal example of what I mean. Probably not important but for full context, this is my actual code: https://github.com/adamerose/pandasgui/blob/develop/pandasgui/widgets/dataframe_viewer.py

I have `class HeaderView(QtWidgets.QTableView):` and I override the click and hover events so it acts like a QHeaderView but allows multiple rows... but since QHeaderView styling changes by theme I can't manually code that so I want it to just inherit whatever styling a QHeaderView would have if it were one

Comment: You cannot, they're different widgets that paint themselves with completely different methods. Btw, have a look at [Making a specified table using pyqt5 designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63096126) which might help you in understanding how to implementing a multiple row header (and, indirectly, why you cannot just "inherit" a stylesheet of a different class).

Comment: @musicamante Thats too bad, ok thanks for answering. I will probably just write my own stylesheet to apply directly to the instance and try to design it so it looks ok with any theme.